# How do you get the Self Destruct Gesture in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

My brother and I have finished the co-op mode in Portal 2 and I have finished the solo mode (twice), but we haven't gotten the self destruct yet! I know there is a self destruct gesture because I saw this guy use it in the walkthrough for Portals 2 co-op.

How do you get the Self Destruct Gesture in Portal 2?

Comment: What platform are you playing on?  Also, what platform was the walkthrough from (can you provide a link)?

Answer (score 2):

Self destruct is not a gesture, but you can self destruct yourself by opening the [PC console](http://www.gamefront.com/portal-2-dev-console-cheats/) and typing "explode."  Note that recent patches to Portal 2 may have [disabled this functionality](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2230832) or marked it as a "cheat."

I don't believe it is possible to do this in the console versions of the game.

For reference, the 8 [base gestures](http://www.trueachievements.com/a149573/gesticul8-achievement.htm) are:

1. Highfive
2. Waving
3. Dancing (Doing the Robot)
4. Rock Paper Scissors
5. Laughing
6. Taking off your partners head
7. Hugging
8. Kung-Fu

There are also a set of DLC gestures for both [Atlas](http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Atlas_gestures) and [P-Body](http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/P-body_gestures), but none of these are "self destruct" either.

Comment: You could bind a gesture followed by explode with the console or config files. Waving would probably be particularly fitting.